# Private set of users for iOS App

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to create an iOS App for a limited set of people.

It should be possible to download the app for free from App Store, but in order to use it
the idea is that you are required to be a member of the organization, which in this case is a local sports organization.

To solve the problem I thought of giving away activation keys to members that can be entered when they create an account, and therefore only members will be using the app.

Will the app be rejected by App Store? If so, is it possible to go around this in some away?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the app will be rejected by the App Review. They do not let in house apps to the app store. You should try enterprise distribution. Good luck!

Comment: @FahriAzimov I wouldn't be so sure. There's an app for accessing OwnCloud service for students and employees of some Canadian Univ. So, it is possible. Upd: asks ownCloud

Comment: I think there will be no rejection. You need to to give some demo accounts to review while submitting to appstore.

Comment: What I'm worried about is 2.22 11.1 11.2 and 11.3 [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). Could you tell me why this senario wouldn't be any of these cases? @Alex

Answer (score 2):

No you will not be rejected by the App Store.

During the review you will only need to give the access to demo account.

Your app will be available to anyone but you are free to give the credential to any person you want.

edit 
Fyi I have such apps. The AppStore only block 'discriminating' app based on carrier or location (you can choose the countries anyway), but you are perfectly in the rules if you give access only to your clients...

edit edit

2.22 like I said is against arbitrary criterias, not linked to the login mechanism

for 11.1 and so on, I understand the point, but in my case (and I think yours) there is no problem if

- you sell your service before, the app is just complimentary
- you dont sell anything within the app
- you dont charge for the app itself or anything within the app, you charge only the use of the server/back office/whatsoever

I guess that Apple dont care, they just don't want to bypass the applestore but I dont think that it is your case.

Comment: Hi and thanks for you answer @david . Are you completely sure about this? Since **2.22** **11.1** **11.2** and **11.3** [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) is what is against the solution

Answer (score 1):

You should try Enterprise distribution for such purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your app may be rejected. Check the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/). In 2.2 it says

> Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected

There are different alternatives.

- You can opt in for the [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/), this'll cost you 300$ a year and requires you to be a legal entity.
- If you want to test it with a limited number of people (<1000) try looking into [Testflight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) it was bought by Apple and is deeply integrated in the development process.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. Testflight won't work in my case as we have 3000-4000 potential users. I'll have a look on the Enterprise program.

Comment: As stated by others here they don't seem to be to strict on this point. So it is probably worth a shot distributing it and unlocking it with an activation key. If your app is rejected you can still opt in for the more expensive enterprise solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, there will not. You need to to give some demo account info as test data to review while submitting to app store in the iTunes Connect portal.

Demo use case(worked for me): Implementation is like, there need some userid/unique pin to the registered account holders to start the application. At the time they input this pin, authenticate the user with our server and give the permission to let in to the app.

Otherwise you need to go for enterprise distribution. Find more about enterprise distribution [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html).